# VB 2008 Service Based Database to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I am not good in Visual Basic But I have a project and I am stuck and need your help.

I created a database project, I simply created from `NEW -> Service Based Database` and made a project now I have to install this program in my office on SQL Server because my project has something link admin panel to add info and I want my colleagues to see this news, but I don't know how to switch Service Based Database to SQL Server. Please if somebody can help me.

Also I want to admit that on youtube I saw that it's easy to make from Add New Dataset than SQL Server -> User and Password and connect like this but there is no SQL Server listed in the NEW CONNECTION Data Source.

I am using VB 2008 and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand What is **Service based database** :

Basically, a service-based database is when the database is stored on a server. To access the database, you need to have the SQL Server service running....hence the "service-based". You connect to the server, query the database, and get the information back.

So as long their is SQL Server service running this data will work all you need is just modify your **connection string** , Actually if you are using same Database, the connection string is always the same. The only thing that you will change is the value, which are the database name, user id, password and the source ("localhost" or any IP Address that you will be connected).